# connect impedance parallel to 3 phase load

Tags: voltage, current, ac, three-phase

Suppose we have a 3 phase load connected to a 3 phase voltage source and connect a capacitor parallel to one of the phase loads like in the image below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxEu3I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How do we solve this kind of circuit?The current flowing through the neutral is not 0 right?How do we find the voltage across the resistor R4?

Comment: If you want a purely numerical answer I'd use a simulator.

Comment: I want to know how to solve this circuit.\

Answer (score 3):

Three voltage sources connected via three independent series impedances to a star point where, the star-point has an impedance to ground is crying out for Millman's theorem to be used: -

[image]

Picture taken from [this slideshow](https://www.slideshare.net/SyedHasanSaeed/millmans-theorem).

Regarding the equations, it's this from [this tutorial](http://www.abcofelectronics.com/milliman.html): -

[image]

If one of the sources is zero volts (as per the voltage in series with R4 in the question) then, it makes no difference; it becomes 0 volts and one of the terms in the numerator of the equation above disappears.

Make sure you use the correct phasor or complex number notation in solving the answer.

Comment: Does it apply to voltage sources which are out of phase?

Comment: @RobSmith of course.

Comment: so for each voltage I replace it with the polar form of the voltage correct?

Comment: @RobSmith correct, polar or rectangular, whichever is your preference.